# Weird PHP json_encode error: json_encode() expects at most 2 parameters, 3 given

Tags: php, json

This code:

```
$arr = array(
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => array(
        'c' => 'Hello',
        'd' => [1, 10, 100, 1001]
    ),
);

echo json_encode($arr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT, 2);
```

Generates this error:

> json_encode() expects at most 2 parameters, 3 given

However the last time I checked, [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) does accept a 3rd argument.

I want to expand the JSON string by less depths. Ain't the 3rd the solution here? But why does it give this error while PHP doc says it accepts 3?

FYI I'm on WAMP with PHP 5.4.

Comment: The `depth` parameter was added in php5.5. It's written in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the page you link to:

> 5.5.0 depth parameter was added.

Since you are using PHP 5.4, your version of PHP is too old to support the third argument. PHP 5.4 is also past [end of life](http://php.net/supported-versions.php).

Upgrade to a supported version of PHP. Preferably a 7.x branch as no 5.x branch has a status better than "security fixes only".